# jquery.inputmask - set value in "oncomplete" callback makes incorrect action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit, jquery-inputmask

If in "oncomplete" callback make setVal action with other masked input, you can see incorrect reactions in Chrome and Safary, well work in FF

```
oncomplete: function(e){
    $('.i-input-2').val($(e.currentTarget).inputmask('unmaskedvalue'));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/serGlazkov/nxLzq82o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this bug fixed in version 3.2.2

Answer (score 7):

It seems as though you have uncovered a critical bug with the jQuery inputmask plugin.  There is some aggressive caret position handling when using `autoGroup` and `digitsOptional` options.  When combined with multiple masked input instances it causes the caret to moved to index 0 after every keystroke.

Using the `currency` mask with the following options will give you the most consistent interface.

```js
$('.i-input-1').inputmask({
    alias: 'currency',
    rightAlign: false,
    digits: 2,
    oncomplete: function (e) {
        var currVal = $(e.currentTarget).inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
        copyValue1(currVal);
    }
});

$('.i-input-2').inputmask({
    alias: 'currency',
    rightAlign: false,
    digits: 2
});

function copyValue1(str){
    $('.i-input-2').val(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev.vanare.net/bundles/vanarewebsite/js/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="i-input-1" value="100">
<input type="text" class="i-input-2" value="555" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: if you make "digits: 0" bug happen again